# model test p-value>0.05 but intrcpt <0.05

Tags: interpretation, meta-analysis, meta-regression

Mixed-Effects Model (k = 21; tau^2 estimator: SJ)

tau^2 (estimated amount of residual heterogeneity):     0.2301 (SE = 0.0752)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):             0.4797
I^2 (residual heterogeneity / unaccounted variability): 93.30%
H^2 (unaccounted variability / sampling variability):   14.92
R^2 (amount of heterogeneity accounted for):            0.00%

```
Test for Residual Heterogeneity:
QE(df = 19) = 494.7195, p-val < .0001

Test of Moderators (coefficient 2):
F(df1 = 1, df2 = 19) = 0.4029, p-val = 0.5331

Model Results:

                      estimate      se     tval    pval    ci.lb   ci.ub 
intrcpt                 0.7497  0.1143   6.5572  <.0001   0.5104  0.9889  *** 
fidelity_assessmentY   -0.3183  0.5014  -0.6348  0.5331  -1.3676  0.7311      

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Dear group,

Thank you for your replies regarding my previous post. I have one more question regarding the meta-regression results. I divided studies into "with fidelity assessment (Y)" and "without fidelity assessment (N)". The test of moderators shows that p-value is 0.5331. However p-value for the intrcpt is <.0001. Based on the previous post, I understand that this means that the group without fidelity assessment is significant. My question is that since the moderator test says that p-value is 0.5331, can I still draw the conclusion that the intercpt group is significant?

Comment: Based on the previous post, I understand that this means that the group without fidelity assessment is significant. Please  clarify.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the table is telling you that the estimate for the reference level "without fidelity assessment (N)" is significantly different from zero (p value `<.0001`). And the estimate of the other level "with fidelity assessment (Y)" is not significantly different from the reference level estimate (N) (p value `0.5331`).

So yes, your reference level in the intercept is significant.

Comment: Thanks! But since the test of moderators shows that p-value is 0.5331, does this result make sense?

Comment: If ML wants to test whether each level is different from zero then removing the intercept from the model is the way to go.

Comment: @mdewey I do not think that the exercise should  help the OP.

Comment: @user2974951 Your statement seems to sugget that <.0001 = 0. interesting and funny. Further, comparing to reference - what is being compared with - the p-value or estimate ? What will it represent? please avoid abrasive language that could mislead the reader like me who is not well-versed with Englsh.

Comment: @M.L Can you run an ANOVA on your model?

Comment: Your answer to the questions raised could help the community to assess your answer. Anova  and meta regression do not substitue each other.

Comment: There exsits  nothing like a "intercpt group" at least in statistics . The correct interpretation is that fidelity has insignificant i.e.no role  in determining the  effect-size of postulated dependent variable. I am surely not going to post it as an answer because there are a few psuedo-staticians working on this extremely useful site for future learning.